# Can we add rendering in body-top placeholder in Partial design?

Tags: sxa

We would like to add one div at the top of #wrapper in Sitecore SXA 1.8.

[image]

Would like to add extra div through `Content Editor`. I don't want to add in layout view.

I tried to add `metadata partial design` to add div at the top of #wrapper under `body-top` placeholder and added under `Page Designs`. It is showing on the page and working fine. Same scenario I need it into the `Partial Design`. There , we don't  have any provision to add `metadata partial design` in `Partial design`. So I have added rendering at `Partial design` in `Presentation` tab `Details` button and provided `body-top` placeholder to it.

[image]

Only concern here, we will use `body-top` placeholder for `metadata partial design` as it shows there. Can we use this placeholder in `partial design` as it does not show there but when we add rendering through Presentation tab then it shows in html.

**Partial Design :-**

[image]

**Metadata Partial Design :-**

[image]

Comment: Hope this [document](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-metadata-partial-design.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note here is, if you add anything in partial design, those placeholder will be locked and you might get into troubleshooting as to why ADD HERE button is not showing up and placeholder when you edit page item and it will be locked for editing

https://daivagnananavati.blogspot.com/2021/08/sitecore-sxa-add-here-button-not.html

see above blog I faced similar issue, Hope it helps !!!